# Prove $f(x)=1/x$ not differentiable at $x = 0$.

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

Prove $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ not differentiable at $x = 0$.

Suppose $f(x)$ differentiable at $x=0$, then by definition 
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$ 
exists.  But this means that 
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{x+h}-\frac{1}{0}}{h}$$ 
exists, however $\frac{1}{0}$ is not defined so then the limit does not exist, which leads to a contradiction.

Is this correct or is there a better and more rigourous way to prove this?

Comment: Note that the domain of $1/x$ excludes $0$.  What can one automatically state?

Comment: Yea I think my confusion was just with the fact of considering points outside the domain of the function.  Now it makes sense: the derivative of the function is the collection of pairs $(a, \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h})$ where a is in the domain of $f$ and the limit exists.  Is this a correct statement?

Comment: The function is not continuous at $x=0$, can you tell something from that?

Comment: It's not even defined yet at $0.$ How do you define $f(0)$? Regardless, the function would always be discontinuous at that point since the limits from both ends fail to agree, and become unbounded.

Comment: To give a function the chance to be continuous (or have any other property) at some point it must exist at that point ...

Answer (score 2):

Since $x=0$ is not in the domain of $f(x)$, you can immediately assume that $f(x)$ will not be differentiable at $x=0$. However, you can still show that $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is not differentiable at $x=0$ using the limit definition:

$\lim\limits_{h\to0} \dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \lim\limits_{h\to0} \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{x+h}-\dfrac{1}{x}}{h} = \lim\limits_{h\to0} \dfrac{\dfrac{x}{x(x+h)}-\dfrac{x+h}{x(x+h)}}{h} = \lim\limits_{h\to0} \dfrac{-h}{x(x+h)}\cdot\dfrac{1}{h} = $

$\lim\limits_{h\to0} \dfrac{-1}{x(x+h)} = \dfrac{-1}{x^2}$.

Since $f'(x) = \dfrac{-1}{x^2}$ is not defined at $x=0$, $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Answer (score 2):

For a derivative to be existing, it need to be continuous in the first place.To be continuous, left and right limit should be equal to the value at that point. Now it is not defined at 0, meaning not continuous hence not differentiable. Also we can show as below that left and right limit are not same and hence discontinuous.

$f(x^+)=\lim\limits_{h \to 0}f(x+h)=\dfrac{1}{x+h}$ for $x>0$

$f(0^+)=\dfrac{1}{h}>0$

but

$f(x^-)=\lim\limits_{h \to 0}f(x-h)=\dfrac{1}{x-h}<0$

$f(0^-)=\dfrac{1}{-h}<0$

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be observing that the domain of $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ excludes $x=0$. If we evaluate $f(x)$ at $x=0$ then we get $f(0)=\frac{1}{0}$, which is undefined. Alternatively, you could recognize that the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is only differentiable at $x=0$ if

$$ f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}$$

exists. Evaluating the limit at $x=0$ forms

\begin{align}f'(0)&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}\\&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1/h-f(0)}{h}\end{align}

which doesn't exist because

$$f(0)=\frac{1}{0}$$

doesn't exist and because

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h^2}$$

also doesn't exist.